# Parameter's purpose

Tags: javascript, html

Im doing a project right now where certain elements of the page change depending on the mouse positioning and made some code basing myself off an explanation I saw in Mozilla. I understand most of it, but there is still one part that is bothering me, which is the function parameter. Throughout my learning of basic Javascript, I have never understood parameters despite the countless explanations. What does a parameter do? How does the page know its purpose? To give an example here is the code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Change</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="hurb"></p>

<script>
document.addEventListener('mousemove', movee);

function movee(a) {
    var eub = a.clientX;
    document.getElementById("hurb").innerHTML = eub;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What does a do here? How does the page know what it does?
Can someone please explain this in a way that can be understandable for a beginner? All the other explanations in pages dont really help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Browsers pass an event object into an event handler function when the event happens.

Comment: A parameter is just some value that a function accepts as input and (presumably) works with potentially producing an output value. Let's take a very basic mathematical function `f(x) = x + 1`. In JavaScript this will be written as `function f(x) { return x + 1; }` or `f = (x) => x + 1`. They all mean the same thing - when the function is given some value `x` (here we expect it to be a number) it returns the value plus one. So `f(2)` is `3` because with `x = 2` you calculate `2 + 1`. That's all a parameter is - some value that comes in later but your code knows how to work with when it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter, as its name suggests, is something upon which usually the function's return value depends. Hence, your function can have a parameter that is not used throughout the function. Here is an example:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("foo");
}

function bar(par1, par2, par3) {
  console.log("bar");
}

foo(); // foo
bar(); // bar
bar(45,100); // bar
```

Note that however you call `bar()` it logs "bar", since the parameter is never used inside the function and hence never contributes to the return value of the function.

In your case, the function is an event handler function, i.e. is called when some event (mousemove in your case) is fired. When an event is fired, the browser passes an Event object (particularly a [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) object in your case) to the event handler function. This event object is a typical JS object, with properties such as `clientX`, `clientY`, `pageX`, `pageY`, etc.... By defining your function with a parameter, that parameter is going to take the value of the Event object. To access the Event object's properties, you do not need to define a parameter for your function. Hence, this function:

```
function movee(a) {
  var eub = a.clientX;
  document.getElementById("hurb").innerHTML = eub;
}
```

and this one:

```
function movee() {
  var a = event;
  var eub = a.clientX;
  document.getElementById("hurb").innerHTML = eub;
}
```

are typical of each other.

> How does the page know its purpose?

The page doesn't. All the page does is that it executes your function. If it encounters the parameter, it uses its value. Otherwise, it just continues execution.